# Audio Queue Services callback: AudioStreamPacketDescription cannot be copied?

Tags: ios, copy, audioqueueservices

I am creating a simple iOS app that records audio with a circular buffer. This means that it continually records audio, but only keeps the last 15 buffers in memory.

I do this by copying all the data I get from the `AudioInputCallback`:

```
void AudioInputCallback(
                    void *inUserData, 
                    AudioQueueRef inAQ, 
                    AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer, 
                    const AudioTimeStamp *inStartTime, 
                    UInt32 inNumberPacketDescriptions, 
                    const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescs)
```

This works great and I can record an `AIF` file correctly when I save all my buffers to a file after I stop recording. So, the copying of the data to other buffers works correctly.

Problem however is that when I use `M4A` that uses variable packets, that same routine does not work. When I put the `AudioFileWritePackets` method in the callback it works correctly, but when I use it afterwards on the stored buffered data, it fails.

It turns out that this is caused by the data of `const AudioStreamPacketDescription *inPacketDescs` When I change that in the callback function itself (recording there) to my copy it fails immediately. However the data itself is identical.

This is the format:

```
struct AudioStreamPacketDescription {
   SInt64  mStartOffset;
   UInt32  mVariableFramesInPacket;
   UInt32  mDataByteSize;
};
typedef struct AudioStreamPacketDescription AudioStreamPacketDescription;
```

I create a copy in my code using the following method:

```
item.inPacketDescs = (AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(malloc(sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription)));

    item.inPacketDescs->mDataByteSize = inPacketDescs->mDataByteSize;
    item.inPacketDescs->mStartOffset = inPacketDescs->mStartOffset;
    item.inPacketDescs->mVariableFramesInPacket = inPacketDescs->mVariableFramesInPacket;
```

However, when then using the `item.inPacketDescs` instead of the `inPacketDescs` makes it fail immediately. And this while the data of these three fields is identical. (I checked using debugger).

I am a bit out of options now. I see that the supplied variable is `const`, so I am afraid that this has some meaningfull purpose, like that the `AudioFileWritePackets` requires it to be the same memory address or so? That would be amazingly stupid, but I don't really know anymore.

Any ideas on what is causing this? Ideas on how to save it differently to a circular buffer?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that `inPacketDescs` is a `array` of `AudioStreamPackedDescription`. 
Therefore copying only the first value was failing.

Solution:

```
AudioStreamPacketDescription * test = (AudioStreamPacketDescription *)(malloc(inNumberPacketDescriptions * sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription)));
    memcpy(test, inPacketDescs, inNumberPacketDescriptions * sizeof(AudioStreamPacketDescription));
```

Comment: how did this worked for you, you are still only updating the test[0] value here

Comment: Not really? I copy over `inNumberPacketDescriptions` amount of `AudioStreamPacketDescription` size, which will be more then 1 of them